# How to find out whether a shell script is written in bash or sh

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

How can I find out whether a script is written in `bash` or `sh`?

The first line of the script is not helpful here, since on Linux, bash scripts have this line:
`#!bin/sh`

Actually, there are many distribution where `/bin/sh` is bash (maybe `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash` in those distributions), and not Bourne Shell. So if I try to run a script that is written in bash in, for example, FreeBSD, the result is not defined, since `/bin/sh` in FreeBSD is Bourne Shell, and not bash.

Is there are easy way to identify if a script is bash or sh?

Are there some distinctive things in syntax?

Comment: See [Bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) on Greg's Wiki...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually the shebang lines means something as some distributions like Debian don't use `bash` for `/bin/sh` but `dash`.

The simplest solution to determine if a shell script is bash is to use [`checkbashism`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/checkbaskisms/) - see [`man checkbashisms`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=checkbashisms&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) for details.

`checkbashisms` should be packaged by different distributions, for Debian it is in the `devscripts` package - Fedora in `devscripts-minimal` (it used to be in `rpmdevtools`) and OpenSuSe in `rpmlint-mini`